# css searchbox is not set in proper place

Tags: html, css

In Css `searchbox` I am getting extra space like below:--

[image]

My jsfiddle link is:--

[Jsfiddle link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaeJpw)

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: What all have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: Click on the jsfiddle link

Comment: it's a codepen link actually :)

Comment: Its same as "jsfiddle"..

Comment: I saw it... that's a single attempt. What all *else* have you tried? Surely you didn't try only 1 thing and then post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the css from 35% can affect the search box.
If you change it to px, it may be useful I guess.
I changed it to around 300px and it was covering that empty space with the button.
Inside .search-wrapper button {}.
Removing the border radius may help to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://codepen.io/kiranm/pen/VvjPbQ)**

```
.search-wrapper input {
width: 74%; /* changed width */
.....
}

.search-wrapper button {   
 position: absolute; 
 width: 15%; /* changed position to absolute and width */
 ........
 }
```

Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to `box-sizing`.

You should apply `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `input` so that the width excludes `padding-left` and `padding-right` from the calculation.

```css
.search-wrapper input {
    width: 60%; /* Keep this at 60% */
    padding: 10px 5px;
    float: left;
    font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    border: 0;
    background: #EEE;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;  /* Apply box-sizing to be on the border box */
}
```

You can then set `width: 40%;` on the button.

```css
.search-wrapper button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 40%; /* Set to 40% */
    font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #D83C3C;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

Now, your input width (60%) + button width (40%) = 100%.

Answer (score 0):

```
.search-wrapper input {
    width: 63%;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    float: left;
    font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    border: 0;
    background: #EEE;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
```

Change your searchbox width